Vim regex search doesn't find match (plus sign)
I have a file open in vim with this content.
if ($_POST['action']=="edit" || $_POST['action']=="add") {

When I do a / to search the pattern \$_POST\['\w, it obviously finds matches:

Additionally, when I add a * onto my search (\$_POST\['\w*), it also finds matches:

However, when I use a + instead of a *, it finds no matches. This is confusing because i thought it should be "one or more occurrence of a word character", shouldn't it?

Why isn't it finding matches?

Some symbols need to be escaped. From :help multi:
              multi
     'magic' 'nomagic'  matches of the preceding atom
/star   *       \*      0 or more       as many as possible
/\+     \+      \+      1 or more       as many as possible
/\=     \=      \=      0 or 1          as many as possible
/\?     \?      \?      0 or 1          as many as possible

